# JavaScript and dynamically creating objects

Tags: javascript

When you call document.createElement(...) on a particular document, does that newly created element only apply to that original document, or can it be inserted into other accessible windows/document trees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can only be inserted in that document, but you can use [`adoptNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.adoptNode) or [`importNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.importNode) to make it accessible in a different document.